# how to give data messages successfully deleted, on select box?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I am making a delete choice using javascript, but I have a few problems when the data is deleted, the website does not load so the data is still on the display. to eliminate it I need to press F5, then the data disappears

```
    function deleteAll() {
if ($('input:checked').length < 1) {
  alert('Pilih data yang akan di hapus!')
} else if (confirm("Apakah yakin akan menghapus semua data terpilih?")) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "zakatfitrah/hapus",
    type: "POST",
    data: $('#form-zfitrah').serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
      table.ajax.reload();
    },
    error: function(data) {
      alert("Tidak Dapat Menghapus Data!");
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Well, what does `table.ajax.reload();` do? We cannot magically guess that...

Comment: you can set to it's <tr> tag a className like `<tr class="tr_{{$item->id}}" data-id="{{$item->id}}">`, and when you click on this you get the `data-id` and then do this in ajax:sucess  `$(".tr_"+variableThatYouGetDataId).css("display","none");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, can you specify how you are displaying messages from ajax response if you are using the following method

```
<div id="myDiv">test</div>
```

ajax response:

```
$('#message').html(result.message);
setTimeout(function()
{
   $('#message').html("");

}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what data you would like to delete. What you'll probably need to do is delete the element that holds the data.

Element:

```
<div id="myDiv">test</div>
```

Delete:

```
$('#myDiv').remove();
```